# How do I put to a three-dimensional, Liskov Map in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, type-inference, liskov-substitution-principle

I am trying to put a Map into another Map.

```
Map<String, ? extends Map<String, String>> test = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
test.put("foobar", temp);
```

But I receive this:

The method put(String, capture#1-of ? extends Map) in the type Map> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Map)

Isn't `Map<String,String>` the same as `? extends Map<String,String>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer `Map` `test` uses an upper wildcard value which prevents values being added whereas the `Map` `temp` does not.

You could use

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> test = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
            ^                                               ^
            |-----changed LHS type--- must be matched with -|
```

The  bounded wildcard syntax `Map<String, ? extends Map<String, String>>` means the `Map` uses a value of some unknown type that extends `Map`. The compiler prevents all values except `null` being added.

Notice also the right hand side value has a `Map` type rather than a `HashMap` as generics are not covariant which means generic types on the right hand side assigned values must match exactly with those from the left hand side declaration.

Comment: I took out `? extends` and changed the inner `HashMap` to a `Map` and I get the same error.

Comment: Did you see I changed the assignment also?

Comment: I posted my comment the second before you edited your question. I'm using a method to get the whole Map and I missed a `? extends`. I read [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html), but I still don't understand why the bounded wildcard prevents non-null elements from being added.

Comment: Java's type reification is non-existent at run time. Generics are only enforced at compilation time. The wildcard can not be enforced at run time, so the compiler kicks it out.

Comment: Ah right, I was just reading about type erasure from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29). Hypothetically, if this could compile, at runtime my Map would look like this: `Map<String, ?> test = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>()`, right?

Comment: @NobleUplift No that still uses a wildcard so wont allow any values to be added to the outer `Map`. Use the syntax above or Puces below if using Java 7

Comment: I didn't mean to say that `?` was a wildcard, more like `Map<String, WHATISTHISIDONTEVEN>`.

As much as I would love to use the diamond operator, I have to retain backwards compatibility with 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java SE 7, consider the diamond operator:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> test = new HashMap<>();
```